# Check if CGRect intersects an array of Rectangles

Tags: objective-c, intersection, cgrect

I'm trying to have a NSView with many different NSTextViews in it, not intersecting each other. At first, I had the idea to do the following:

```
for (NSString *str in frames) {

        while (CGRectIntersectsRect(NSRectToCGRect(field.frame), NSRectToCGRect(NSRectFromString(str)))) {

            CGPoint origin = [self randomPoint];

            field.frame = CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, sizeOfButton.width, sizeOfButton.height);


        }

    }
        NSString *string = NSStringFromRect(field.frame);

        [frames addObject:string];
```

Here, 'frames' is an array to which I add the coordinates of the NSTextViews, once they are cleared and supposedly not intersecting. 'field' is an NSTextField, and 'randomPoint' is a method that randomly finds an NSPoint, so that the placement of the NSTextField is random.

What happens is that I iterate through an array of rectangles, and check against each one of them that the new rectangle doesn't intersect. When he has passed this test, he himself goes into the array and a new text field is brought in.

The problem with this approach is that the NSTextField is checked against one rectangle at a time. Indeed, it might not intersect one rectangle, but intersect the following one, and unfortunately, once its coordinates are modified, it might pass the test, while having intersected the first rectangle.

Now, to simplify, does anyone know of a method, or is it possible to change my code, to check at the same time if an object intersects many other objects? Is it possible to check for an intersection between more than 2 CGRects?

Comment: Why are you storing rects as strings? You can use `+[NSValue valueWithRect:]` to turn an `NSRect` into an `NSValue` and use `-[NSValue rectValue]` later to retrieve the `NSRect`.

Comment: What happens if there is no possible location that will fit your new frame? You'll loop forever trying random points and it will never end.

Comment: You're right about the NSValue approach, but it's just as long as storing the rects in strings; I'm going to prioritize on fixing the main issue first.

Comment: And I know for a fact that there is an appropriate location for each NSTextField; I've sized the NSView based on the maximum size they can have.

Comment: Even if you've calculated the minimum space necessary to ensure all fields have _some_ location to go to, you're still going to have a nondeterministic run time. You're better off picking a single random value, which is an offset, then calculating where that puts you if you treat the offset as an index into the possible pixels where this field could be placed.

Comment: That's quite a good idea, thank you ! Do you have any suggestion on how to detect an intersection between more than 2 CGRects?

Comment: Just test them all in a loop. Your problem with the code you pasted is you're modifying the frame after each test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is cleverly demonstrated here: http://static.mrfeinberg.com/bv_ch03.pdf, it seems that it is foolish and remarkably slow to try to check for multiple rectangle intersections in the manner I was using.

A much more complex and elaborate answer is illustrated in that PDF, which is completely overkill for me, but it might be the only solution in the long run.